# How can I avoid mailman's list membership reminders?

Tags: email, mailing-lists, mailman

I'm subscribed to several mailing lists administered by 'mailman'. Once every month I get a message from `mailman-owner@somewhere.com` entitled

> some-list@somewhere.com mailing list reminder

I'd like for mailman not to send these messages to me. I tried using the web interface, but the options at  `https://www.somewhere.com/mailman/options/users-list` don't seem to include skipping the monthly reminder.

Is there a way for me to avoid these reminder messages (and not have to filter them out)?

Comment: Most certainly by signing up for their service you agreed to something in their TOS that allows them to send monthly emails. Therefore, they are not technically sending you spam.

Comment: @CharlieRB: I'll just drop the spam tag, there's no contention with the list administrator, who's sitting across the hall from me.

Comment: It is most likely something in the server setup - [Mailman-Users Disable monthly membership reminder](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/mailman-users/2008-June/061861.html).

Comment: @CharlieRB: So this cannot be disabled on an individual user basis?

Comment: I am not that familiar with it, but from the link I shared, reminders are set on the individual lists. If you can not find a user option to turn it off, it is likely a setting in Python. In other words, you will need to talk to the administrator who has access to the settings for the server where mailman is running.